# How to show the clicked table row id in the address bar

Tags: php, mysql, iframe

I have a PHP based website for jobs. I echo all the jobs from database in a table below. When i click on a job in table row it shows the job details in an iframe beside the table.

**This is the code of the table and iframe `index.php`**

```
<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"> 
<?php 
    include "job.header.php";
    ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30%"> 
        <div>
<?php
        require "module/job.call.php";
        ?>
        </div>
        </td>
        <td width="60%">
            <iframe name="content" src="../module/job.unclicked.php">
            </iframe>
        </td>
        <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**This is the code that i call jobs from the database `job.call.php`**

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job  where approved='1' ORDER BY `CreatedTime` DESC");

echo "<table id='maintable' class='table-fill' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
<tr>
<th position='fixed' overflow='hidden' width='10%'>Job Title</th> 
<th position='fixed' width='5%'>Company Name</th>
<th width='5%'>Closing Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
    if (strlen($row['positiontitle']) > 20)
        $row['positiontitle'] = substr($row['positiontitle'], 0, 60) . "...";
  echo "<tr ref='job.details.php?id=".$row['id']."' target='content' class='positiontitle-link'>";
  echo "<td><font style='text-shadow: none;'>" . $row['positiontitle'] . "</font></a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['companyname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['closingdate'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

[image]

I want that when i click on the job in the table row then the address bar should take the id of the job. because if someone wants to share the job then they should just send that address for specific job.

**Now it show like this**

[image]

**I want that it should look like this**

[image]

Comment: You want to change the current behaviour - remove the iframe and have the link take the user to a new page with the job information on it--correct?

Comment: instead of iframe, try link to another page, if you want to show in the same page try with ajax and modify your url using HTML5 history API

Comment: Thanks @AbdullaChozhimadathil can you please show me how to change it to ajax.

Comment: refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adduwgys/